# My media query isn't working and I'm nor sure why

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My media query isn't working, and I'm not sure why. I have looked at multiple threads and none of them have worked so far, any help would be appreciated

css

```
@media (min-width: 1750px) {
  .logo{
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Thomas Cook Virtual</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index-css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img src="tcgvt.png" id="logo"></a>
        <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
        <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

        <h1 class="headertext">---</h1>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="service.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="service.php">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="service.php">Help</a></li>
         </ul>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. I copied the code and ran it in my browser, and when I expand the window across my second monitor, the image shifts at ~1755px;

Comment: As Christopher said it seems to be working. Would you be able to supply some images of what you expect it to look like?

Comment: May be you are checking at a screen whose width cannot be more than 1750px, try to check in a bigger screen with higher resolution. Your solution seems to be working well.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I tried it again without changing anything and it all worked. Thanks for your input though!